EF Core: what exactly is the command timeout measured on?
I was previously downloading via EF millions of records without encountering any timeouts, however, after adding a WHERE clause to limit the download to only a few thousand records, I am frequently facing timeouts. This has left me somewhat confused and questioning my understanding of how timeouts are applied.
If data is still being streamed by SQL Server after 30 seconds, does a timeout occur?
Is this difference in behavior certainly caused by the current execution plan performing poorly, or is there another explanation? I'm asking because without the WHERE clause, data starts streaming immediately, but this is clearly not happening with the WHERE clause in place. Could this explain why I'm not getting a timeout in one case (no where) while I'm often stopped by a timeout in the other case (where in place)?

your issue is more in DB than in command timeout, which also can be increased. when you don't have where you do full table scan with no logic, so it is just loads data straight up. Add where and you now have full table scan with logic applied - time increases. If you have millions of records and load only small part - see if you can apply index on your fields in where. Indexes slow down inserts but speedup selects. But not when you select 70% of data in the table

execution plan and command timeout are not connected at all, in mechanical sense. Sure, good execution plan will not need increased command timeout because it can deliver results within smaller window

On execution plan I meant to say that a query that returns a few thousand records should be faster to close that one that returns millions and if this is not the case it must be because the query is inefficient (missing appropriate indices) –

should be faster. Only if it can use indexes to quickly find the rows it needs. Otherwise it has to process all those millions of rows to find matches. The fact WHERE caused delays means that there aren't adequate indexes and possibly the condition itself is too complex. A WHERE EXISTS (....) isn't just a filter, it's an extra query. WHERE SomeColumn IN (.... FROM OtherTable) is essentially a JOIN. LIKE '%blah%' searches in the middle of a field and can't use any indexes

If you want help, post the query. Right now there's no information except the timeout. EF is an ORM, not a way to stream data and not a way to substitute SQL. Bad LINQ queries, eg ones that use explicit JOINs instead of relations, or using "clever" tricks to do stuff that's not possible without loading data on the client, can result in very, very bad and inefficient queries.

@PanagiotisKanavos thank you for the offer. I'm already working on adding indices as suggest by SS itself. I have at least a column whose type needs to be changed to support creating an index, but I should be able to handle the task myself.


If data is still being streamed by SQL Server after 30 seconds, does a timeout occur?

For SQL Server

This property is the cumulative time-out (for all network packets that are read during the invocation of a method) for all network reads during command execution or processing of the results. A time-out can still occur after the first row is returned, and does not include user processing time, only network read time.

SqlCommand.CommandTimeout
So CommandTimeout only runs while waiting for results from the server.  If the server is continuously streaming results, the CommandTimeout won't fire after 30sec.

Ok this is interesting and confirms what I was suspecting although this is not coming from entity framework documentation but I suppose the behavior to be expected is the same.

Entity Framework is a layer on top of ADO.NET, so the relevant documentation is from the underlying ADO.NET provider you are using.
